# jQuery add disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make form validation by **jQuery** and got error when I'm add the attribute - "disabled" to submit button (var s)

My jQuery is:

```
function validateForm() {
    var f = document.forms["shamir"]["fullname"].value;
    var x = document.forms["shamir"]["phone"].value;
    var y = document.forms["shamir"]["club"].value;
    var s = document.forms["shamir"]["submit"];
    var isnum = /^\d+$/.test(x);
    if(!f) {
        alert("fill name");
        return false;
    }
    if(isnum) {
        if (x.length == 10) {
            if(x == 0 || x <= 0111111111 || x == 1111111111 || x == 2222222222
                || x == 3333333333 || x == 4444444444 || x == 5555555555 || x == 6666666666
                || x == 7777777777 || x == 8888888888 || x == 9999999999 || x == 1234567890) {
                alert("fix number");
                return false;
            }
            if(y == "none") {
                alert("select club");
                return false;
            } else {
        jQuery(s).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
        return true;
            }
        } else {
            alert("10 digits");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("error");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am tried this:

```
if(y == "none") {
    alert("select club");
    return false;
} else {
    if(jQuery(s).attr('disabled', 'disabled')) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.....

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: jQuery("forms'id").attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Comment: just replace  if as it is not a conditional check it is setting attribute of disable replace     if(jQuery(s).attr('disabled', 'disabled'))  to attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Answer (score 0):

You gotta turn that form into a jQuery object if you are going to manipulate the DOM on it.

For example this is not a jQuery object - so you cant apply jQuery methods to it.:

```
var s = document.forms["shamir"]["submit"];
```

Instead, you would need to do:

```
var form = $("document.forms");  //convert form to jQuery object
var s = form["shamir"]["submit"]; //work with form object
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried .prop()?

```
jQuery(s).prop('disabled', true)
```

or is():

```
jQuery(s).is(':disabled');
```